# How I can display additional information in my search result in the search box of my map

Tags: dictionary, search, leaflet

Is it possible to get the code of this map :
https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/examples/multiple-layers.html

I want to know how in the search box, we can have the name and the type category of the name...
Thank you

Comment: If you want to get the code for any of the example maps, just go to the website for [Leaflet.Control.Search's documentation](https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/) and select one of the bundles to download from the "Download" section. Once it is downloaded, go to the `examples` dir and select the example you want to view. You can also view the files without downloading by going to the project's GitHub repo and selecting the `examples` dir there.

Comment: I think it's this : view-source:https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/examples/multiple-layers.html     but i don't know where I can get the function which is help me to read in the search box like him (with 2 informations in the search box)... For information, I code in RStudio

Comment: The answer I've provided is in basic javascript. It would be helpful if you include details like the language you are using and what you have tried in the original question.

Comment: For my search box, I use AddsearchFeatures but I don't how to do like this website https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/examples/multiple-layers.html    Indeed, he has 2 informations when he search something

Comment: addSearchFeatures(targetGroups  = c('customer','prospect'),
                     options = searchFeaturesOptions(zoom=10, openPopup=TRUE))      I like when I search a societe name, I have also if it's a customer or a prospect (like in this website  https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/examples/multiple-layers.html  )

Comment: addCirclemarkers(....., label=~society, group="customer") %>% addSearchFeatures(targetGroups  = c('customer','prospect'),
                     options = searchFeaturesOptions(zoom=10, openPopup=TRUE))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the code for any of the example maps, just go to the website for [Leaflet.Control.Search's documentation](https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/) and select one of the bundles to download from the "Download" section. Once it is downloaded, go to the `examples` dir and select the example you want to view. You can also view the files without downloading by going to the [project's GitHub repo](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search) and selecting the `examples` dir there. Then, select the example you want to view.

To create the tooltip under the search bar that contains the name and type, you just need to do a few things. If you check in the [bars data in the `data` dir](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/master/examples/data/bar.geojson.js) inside of the `examples` dir, you can see that the name and type are being set in the example GeoJSON:

```
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "node/500129236",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "node/500129236",
        "addr:city": "Roma",
        "addr:country": "IT",
        "addr:housenumber": "5",
        "addr:postcode": "00184",
        "addr:street": "Piazza della Madonna dei Monti",
        "amenity": "bar",
        "name": "la Bottega del caffe'"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          12.4910927,
          41.8950196
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "node/560446888",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "node/560446888",
        "amenity": "bar",  <------- Establishment type
        "name": "Marani".  <------- Establishment name
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          12.5132952,
          41.8970607
        ]
      }
    }
```

Then in the code for the example you are provided, they have passed a `buildTip` function to the control instance that handles building that tooltip. If your data is set up the same way, you just pass the `amenity` and `name` to the function:

```js
L.control.search({
    layer: poiLayers,
    initial: false,
    propertyName: 'name',
    // Function that returns the tooltip under the search bar:
    buildTip: function(text, val) {
        // Type from GeoJSON. If you changed it in GeoJSON, remember to change it here:
        var type = val.layer.feature.properties.amenity;
        // Returns html tooltip:
        return '<a href="#" class="'+type+'">'+text+'<b>'+type+'</b></a>';
    }
})
.addTo(map);
```

There are also more examples and more detailed information at the [Leaflet.Control.Search GitHub Repo](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search#leaflet-control-search).

Comment: thank you very mucch. Do you have the same for Rstudio please

Comment: what is the language he used ? And what kind of software I need to use?

Comment: I have too many questions. Where i can get the code of this website : https://demography.dola.colorado.gov/CensusAPI_Map/?lat=39&lng=-104.8&z=9&s=50&v=mhi&sn=jenks&cs=mh1&cl=7      is it also javascript code? what is the software can i use to run the code?